# Invalid JSON while submitting spark submit job via NiFi

Tags: json, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-nifi

I am trying to submit a `spark` job where I am setting a `date` argument in `conf` property and I am running it through a script in `NiFi`. However, when I am running the script I am facing an error.
`Spark Submit` Code in the script:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id "$1" --steps '[{"Args":["spark-submit","--deploy-mode","cluster","--jars","s3://tvsc-lumiq-edl/jars/ojdbc7.jar","--executor-memory","10g","--driver-memory","10g","--conf","spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled=false","--conf","currDate='\"$5\"'","--class",'\"$2\"','\"$3\"','\"$4\"'],"Type":"CUSTOM_JAR","ActionOnFailure":"CONTINUE","Jar":"command-runner.jar","Properties":"","Name":"Spark application"}]' --region "$6"
```

and after I run it, I get the below error:

```
ExecuteStreamCommand[id=5b08df5a-1f24-3958-30ca-2e27a6c4becf] Transferring flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=00f844ee-dbea-42a3-aba3-0edcabfc50a2,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1607082757752-507103, container=default, section=223], offset=29, length=-1],offset=0,name=6414901712887990,size=0] to nonzero status. Executable command /bin/bash ended in an error: 
Error parsing parameter '--steps': Invalid JSON:
[{"Args":["spark-submit","--deploy-mode","cluster","--jars","s3://tvsc-lumiq-edl/jars/ojdbc7.jar","--executor-memory","10g","--driver-memory","10g","--conf","spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled=false","--conf","currDate="Fri
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON, which makes it easier to see why its wrong.

In your case, you are wrapping the final 3 values in single quotes `'` rather than double quotes `"`

Your `steps` JSON should look like:

```
[{
"Args": [
    "spark-submit",
    "--deploy-mode",
    "cluster",
    "--jars",
    "s3://tvsc-lumiq-edl/jars/ojdbc7.jar",
    "--executor-memory",
    "10g",
    "--driver-memory",
    "10g",
    "--conf",
    "spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled=false",
    "--conf",
    "currDate='\"$5\"'",
    "--class",
    "\"$2\"",
    "\"$3\"",
    "\"$4\""
],
"Type": "CUSTOM_JAR",
"ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
"Jar": "command-runner.jar",
"Properties": "",
"Name": "Spark application"
}]
```

Specifically, these 3 lines:

```
"\"$2\"",
"\"$3\"",
"\"$4\""
```

Instead of the original:

```
'\"$2\"',
'\"$3\"',
'\"$4\"'
```